# Infinite "if" clause?

Tags: probability

Hi I have the following problem and I'm not sure how I can solve it since there are infinite ways that one of the players will win:

two players A and B are flipping coins, A starts.
you flip the coin again and again till you get T, and then you transfer the coin to the other player(B).
you keep playing like this till someone gets H and H again (in a row)[which will make the flipping player the winner].

$P_1$ is the probability to get H as A, and $P_2$ is the probability to get H as B.

Now I'm trying to find out what is the probability of winning for player A but I'm stuck on a loop since there are infinite ways that A can win (A can get T and then B T till infinite)

Comment: When you say "to get $H$" do you mean any heads, or do you mean get two heads in a row?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews to get heads and then heads again in the same turn (H H is good but H T H is bad)

Comment: You never get $HTH$ in your turn, of course, since your turn stops when you get $T$. The phrasing is odd, because everywhere else you use H to mean one head result. You should probably say "$P_1$  is the probability of $A$ winning, and $P_2$ is the probability of $B winning.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I didnt explain myself well, I only now understand your question $P_1$ is the probability to get heads (as the player A) but getting heads doesnt mean you win cause you need to get heads twice in a row to win, and its true that in one turn you will never get H T H since at T your turn stops

Comment: It's still unclear why you define $P_1$ and $P_2$, given that they are not the probalities you are seeking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews its because the coin is probably biased (I myself not entirely sure but its the only logical reason that it was defined) when you flip the coin as A you have a different chance to get H than when you flip it as B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your comment, with simplified notation,
Let $P(A$ gets a head) $= a$ and $P(B$ gets a head) $= b$.

We can solve without summing to infinity. Let us just consider $A$ winning

$A$ can win in $2$ turns with $Pr = a^2\,\;$ or pass the turn to $B$ with $Pr = (1-a^2)$ and be back at square one if $B$ doesn't win $(Pr = 1-b^2)$

So if $p$ is the **overall** probability of A winning,

$p = a^2 + (1-a^2)(1-b^2)\cdot p,\;$ which yields

$p = \dfrac{a^2}{1-(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}$

**PS**

In the particular case that $a=b=1/2, p = 4/7$

---

**ADDED** *another method*

$P(A$ wins on his first chance$) = a^2$

$P(A$ loses on his first chance and $B$ wins) $= (1-a^2)b^2$

This ratio will keep on repeating, so odds in favor of $A = {a^2}:{(1-a^2)b^2}$

$P(A\;\; wins) = \dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + (1-a^2)b^2}= \dfrac{a^2}{a^2+b^2-a^2b^2}$

Comment: Thanks this answer really starts to "click" in my head but in your first equation something I didnt understand: did you multiple by $p$ again in the end? is it like saying if "A didn't win and also B didnt win and also A has won overall"

Comment: The whole point is that if A doesn't win and B doesn't win, A has the same **overall** probability $p$ of winning as at start, that's why we multiply by $p$.

Comment: As another sidelight, it is interesting to note that if the game is changed so that each toss **two** coins turn by turn, (passing to the other if they don't get two heads), the result remains the same.

Comment: I am also adding another (possibly simpler) solution using **odds**

Answer (score 2):

We first note that 
$$\mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins}) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A \textrm{ wins in $n$ turns}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins in $n$ turns})$$
So we must determine $\mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins in $n$ turns})$ for all $n\ge1$.

For $A$ to win in $n$ turns, $A$ and $B$ must loose their turn $n-1$ times and $A$ must win in turn $n$.
To loose your turn, you must either flip head and then tails or tails, which has probability $\frac{3}{4}$. Winning is flipping two heads, which has probability $\frac{1}{4}$. Thus we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins in $n$ turns}) = \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{2(n-1)} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4}{16} \left( \frac{9}{16} \right)^{n-1}.$$
Therefore we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins})  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{16} \left( \frac{9}{16} \right)^{n-1} = \frac{4}{16} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \frac{9}{16} \right)^{n} = \frac{4}{16} \frac{1}{\frac{7}{16}} = \frac{4}{7}.$$

If $A$ and $B$ have different probability of flipping head, say $p_a$ and $p_b$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins in $n$ turns}) = \left( 1 - p_a^2 \right)^{n-1} \left( 1- p_b \right)^{n-1} p_a^2.$$
Since $A$ has to lose his turn $n-1$ times with probability $(1 - p_a) + p_a (1-p_a)=1-p_a^2$ by flipping tails or flipping head and then tails and likewise for $B$. This gives
$$\mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ wins})  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_a^2 \left( (1-p_a^2) (1-p_b^2) \right)^{n-1} = \frac{p_a^2}{1 - (1-p_a^2) (1-p_b^2)} = \frac{p_a^2}{ p_a^2 + p_b^2 -p_a^2 p_b^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is (not involve infinite sum):

First, it is easy to prove that $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{infinite game})=0$, thus $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{A win})+\mathbb{P}(\textrm{B win})=1$.
Let $x=\mathbb{P}(\textrm{original player A win})$.

Consider player A:

- If A get a tail, or a head and a tail, then $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{B win})=x\iff \mathbb{P}(\textrm{A win})=1-x$. That occur $3\over4$ of the time.
- If A get two heads, A win. That occur $1\over4$ of the time.

Thus:
$$x=\frac34\times (1-x)+\frac14\times 1\iff x=\frac47$$

Comment: Yes, one way of looking at this is the symmetry of the game. $x$ is the conditional probability that the current player, at the start of his turn, will win (conditional because it is coditional on the event that the game continues.)

Comment: We kind of "ignored" the rest of the cases (A lose turn B lose turn A lose turn B lose turn A win, for example) because of symmetry?

Comment: No, because that (infinite loop) case has probability 0. What do you mean by saying `A lose turn B lose turn A lose turn B lose turn A win` be `the rest`?

Comment: If I interpret it correctly, @TheOne thinks that this is only the case that $A$ wins the first round or $A$ loses, $B$ loses and $A$ wins, and not $ABAB$ loses and $A$ wins or $ABABAB$ loses and $A$ wins etc.

Comment: @Hetebrij yes this is what I meant

Comment: The case A lose is not ignored, it is counted, that is why the formula of the first case is $\frac34\times (1-x)$. $\frac34$ is the probability of A turn, and $x$ is the probability of $B$ win after that $\iff (1-x)$ is the probability of $A$ win at that case.